# find_first_of of string conflicts for special char pie "|"

Tags: c++, string, stdstring

In the following code i am finding "||" in a text which contains "|", but still it says it exist ? how to resolve this ?

```
std::string  sInputText = "test||111";
std::string delimeter = "||";

int pos = 0;
found = sInputText.find_first_of(delimeter);
if (found == string::npos)
{

}
```

Comment: std::string  sInputText = "test|111";
std::string delimeter = "||";

int pos = 0;
found = sInputText.find_first_of(delimeter);
if (found == string::npos)
{

}

Answer (score 0):

Read the spec....

> Searches the string for the first character **that matches any** of the characters specified in its arguments.